# Angular ng-multiselect-dropdown populate with an array of objects

Tags: angular, ng-dropdown-multiselect

This is my code in the html for a ng-multiselect-dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="paisActivo != '-1'">
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
            [placeholder]="'[Seleccione Marca]'"
            [data]="dataMarcas"
            [(ngModel)]="adminTresActivos"
            [settings]="dropdownSettings"
            (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
            (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
            [class]="'form-control custom-form-control'"
    >
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
```

Currently, `dataMarcas` returns an array:

```
marcas: [
    'ABC',
    'XYD',
    'ETC',
]
```

But now I have to populate the dropdown with an Array like this:

```
[
  {icon: "aquiles.png", id: 853, name: "AQUILES"},
  {icon: "arkan.png", id: 855, name: "ARKAN"}.
  etc
]
```

I have to populate it with the `name` property. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include `textField: 'name'` in your `dropdownSettings`. [ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown)